# echoing session variable and then unseting session variable dont show session variable

Tags: php, session, redirect, scope

```
page1.php

$_SESSION['sVar'] = 'XYZ';
header('Location:page1.php');

page1.php
echo $_SESSION['sVar']; // Works well

page1.php
echo  $_SESSION['sVar']; // donot get displayed after adding following line
unset($_SESSION['sVar']);
```

My Question is : When I am echo session variable it works well but when i destroy that variable after echo its not getting echo.

Comment: Add a request counter in your session. Output as well the request number. You might see that on the *next* request it does not get output - which would be correct. Also keep in mind that `header()` does not end the current request and all the following code is executed (including unsetting the session var) which is likely the part you oversee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me

session1.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sVar'] = 'somecrap';
    header("Location: session2.php");
    exit;
```

session2.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['sVar'];
    unset($_SESSION['sVar']);
```

Obviously if I refresh session2.php I get an undefined index warning

Are you starting the session in both pages?

Comment: ya sesion is started But I found that i had not added exit();

Comment: @mukund Could you add all your code to your question it looks to me like there is extra code that's missing and it may be cause of the issue

Comment: Well whole code might not be possible to add but i found i have many lines of code below it so. It may creating problem to it. And I jst make it to exit after header location so it worked well.